# Go, understanding Context with value

Tags: go

recently i decided to take a look at the context package and i feel i get the hang of it. However, in a video i saw this odd looking line of code, partly i understood it but not the last bit.

I did not include the entire code of that vidoe because i feel like its irrelevant. My question however is, what this this mean: ".(*log.Entry)". Thanks for replies, i have seen this in multiple examples but it is never explained, is it converting log which i believe is an interface{}, to *log.Entry?

```
func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request {
  log, ok := r.Context().Value(logger).(*log.Entry)
  ...
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a type assertion. The value obtained from `r.Context().Value(logger)` is an `interface{}`, and the type assertion checks that the underlying value is a pointer to `log.Entry`, and it it is, it set `ok` to true, and `log` to the value of type `*log.Entry`. Otherwise `ok` will be false (and `log` will be a `nil` of type `*log.Entry`).

See the language specification: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions